# Compare line excel and line table sql

Tags: c++

I will need help or leads for a seemingly simple problem but I am blocking a lot on it. (I'm still a beginner in C ++ / mysql)
I have to fill a table of my database under MySQL by importing the data from a .csv file (it's OK, I succeeded) but before doing this import, I must compare the data of my first line , second, third etc ... until the end of the excel file (which corresponds to the names of the columns that there must be in my table) with the name of the columns of my table under MySQL in order to verify that we have a good scheduling and we put the right data in the right places.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: BTW, a CSV file is not an Excel file.  Excel files usually have the extension ".xls" or a derived form.  Most Excel files are of proprietary format (Microsoft charges for a description of the file format).